# jquery can't get data attribute value

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set a variable in jQuery. The value is supposed to be set on the click event of the button. The onclick event fires but the x10Device variable remains `undefined`.

I am on jquery 1.7.1.

jQuery:

```
 $x10Device = $(this).data("X10");
```

HTML:

```
<button class="toggleStatus" data-X10="C5">
```

I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Insufficient information. Please share some more code.

Comment: jQuery may convert attribute names to all lower-case, try: `$(this).data("x10");`

Comment: Why is the answer closed as unclear ??

Comment: I voted to re-open the question. It is quite clear what is being asked, and the traffic the question receives shows that it is a fairly common problem.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

jQuery's `data()` method will give you access to `data-*` attributes, BUT, it clobbers the case of the attribute name. You can either use this:

```
$('#myButton').data("x10") // note the lower case
```

Or, you can use the `attr()` method, which preserves your case:

```
$('#myButton').attr("data-X10")
```

Try both methods here: http://jsfiddle.net/q5rbL/

Be aware that these approaches are not completely equivalent. If you will **change** the `data-*` attribute of an element, you should use `attr()`. `data()` will read the value once initially, then continue to return a cached copy, whereas `attr()` will re-read the attribute each time.

Note that jQuery will also convert hyphens in the attribute name to camel case ([source](http://xenforo.com/community/threads/html-5-data-attributes-and-case-sensitivity.15609/) -- i.e. `data-some-data == $(ele).data('someData')`). Both of these conversions are in conformance with the HTML specification, which dictates that custom data attributes should contain no uppercase letters, and that hyphens will be camel-cased in the `dataset` property ([source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute)). jQuery's `data` method is merely mimicking/conforming to this standard behavior.

**Documentation**

- `data` - http://api.jquery.com/data/
- `attr` - http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- HTML Semantics and Structure, custom data attributes - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute

Comment: Also with .data(), when you use Camel Case like $(this).data("giveMeMyBananas") it will retrieve the html data of data-give-me-my-bananas="NO!"

Comment: Added that note, @BabyAzerty, as well as part of the reason for it (the HTML spec dictates custom attributes contain no capital letters)

Comment: @JasonMillington Glad to help! Check the note I put in about `attr()` vs. `data()` -- you might be more interested in `attr()` anyway, depending on how you will use the attributes.

Comment: I also found that `data()` will return an integer e.g. `1` whereas `attr()` returns a string, e.g. `"1"`. This just means use `==` to compare, instead of `===`.

Comment: I would rather say that data() stores the data in memory, while attr() stores on the DOM (html), so do not mix both functions when dealing with one specific element. So it means that you will never face the problem with the cached value from data()

Comment: Surely whether stored in cache/memory or DOM, changing the data value should change the data value. I appreciate and am helped by the warning about using attr when the data value will change but it make *no* sense to me that calling data to set a new value doesn't just reset the cache value as well.

Answer (score 3):

Iyap . Its work 
Case sensitive in data name
data-x10

`var variable = $('#myButton').data("x10");` // we get the value of custom data attribute

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check if the event related to the button click is not propagating to child elements as an icon tag (`<i class="fa...`) inside the button *for example*, so this propagation can make you miss the button `$(this).attr('data-X10')` and hit the icon tag.

```
<button data-x10="C5">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Text
</button>

$('button.toggleStatus').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-X10');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use plain javascript methods

```
$x10Device = this.dataset("x10");
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the casing to all lowercases worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the selector and data attributes as you wish!

```
 <select id="selectVehicle">
       <option value="1" data-year="2011">Mazda</option>
       <option value="2" data-year="2015">Honda</option>
       <option value="3" data-year="2008">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="4" data-year="2005">Toyota</option>
  </select>

$("#selectVehicle").change(function () {
     alert($(this).find(':selected').data("year"));
});
```

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ed5axgvk/1/