# Jquery return to source CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to change an element back to it's source CSS(The CSS it loaded with)

I have for example an `input`, in which I change the border to `red` when it's empty on submit.

Is there a way to change it back to normal without saving the original values in a variable?

Comment: I think you need to duplicate that node, then switch back when it is necessary to have original node. This is huge performance hit. To answer your question Yes it does, you can use it any time

Comment: I know the original css is saved in the source (which does not change even when javascript mess with the elements).

Question if I can use that...

Comment: No you cannot use that as jQuery doesn't directly edit that but adds inline styles which take precedence over external styles (in most cases)

Comment: Agree with @undefined if you've got the power to edit JS on the page in question, you can include your own stylesheets with defined classes you can `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: As long as you don't use inline styles as default, and only let javascript set inline styles, you can easily just remove the style attribute, in jQuery it would be `$(element).removeAttr('style')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you set the border via `.css("border","1px solid red")` or something alike.
jQuerys css() function sets the style inline; it modifies the style attribute:

```
<input style="border:1px solid red;" />
```

Styles defined in a CSS file are overwritten by inline styles.
To reset the style, the best way is to delete the inline-style by passing something useless to the browser, normally an empty string:

```
$("input").css("border","");
```

The browser can't render that rule and will fall back to the rules defined in your CSS file.

If you wish to reset the style to the browser's default, use the "initial" keyword.

Comment: Worked, I donno why have I never tested it.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery modifies the style attribute when you change css, so I think you can just reset the style attribute, assuming that you didn't have any inline styles of yourself. If you do have inline styles, then this won't work, obviously. But, well, you shouldn't have. :)

```
yourElement.attr('style', '');
```

Comment: wrong...this would only work when there is no style on element and would remove the styles if there was any (*by default*), not *revert* to original - what OP's asking, assume i did -1! :)

Answer (score 1):

Logically, 2 ways i can think of :

- Save you default style in some `data-` attribute in HTML (*alert : HTML5 only*), to revert to original, fetch the value from this attribute using jQuery and set it in your element!
  look here on how to get `data-` attribs value : [jquery can't get data attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351282/jquery-cant-get-data-attribute-value)
- Preferred : Rather than directly applying css through jQuery, use CSS `class`, like `.error{}` and then to change back to original, use [`addclass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)  and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)  as per your requirements