# Save attributes to values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attributes

In my current program I am trying to pull the data-price value and the value=" " as well. I know I need to somehow implement the

```
$(this).attr( )
```

but it isn't pulling the right information. 
I am trying to declare a value called id for the seat name and value price for seat cost whenever the checkbox is selected. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/pnuqyyqh/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get you started:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function(){
        getPropChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
        if(getPropChecked)
        {
            getId = $(this).prop("id");
            getValue = $(this).attr("value");
            getDataPrice = $(this).attr("data-price");
            alert("getId: " + getId + 
              " getValue: " + getValue +  
              " getDataPrice:" + getDataPrice);
        }
    })
})
```

[Please refer to this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351282/jquery-cant-get-data-attribute-value)

Comment: Ok so I needed to use the .on() function. this is actually the first time I have seen/used the "input[type=checkbox]" before

Comment: You don't need to use the `on`. You were simply using `$(this)` in the wrong place since it was out of scope.

Comment: oh ok. Also, why didn't you have to declare var before getId?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional

Answer (score 0):

You obtain a data attribute with `$(this).data('price');` and its value with `$(this).val()`

Comment: Weirdest thing. When I use $(this).val() I get a `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined' from my meta: ` <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` ??

Comment: It's not weird, `$(this)` references the checkbox input on the click callback function. Your update function does not know what `$(this)` means. I'm going to edit your jsFiddle.