# How to store multiple drop down values inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this javascript function that loops through each user account and displays them in a drop-down menu. When the user selects an option from the drop-down menu, it takes the Iban number as its main id which is stored in ddlAccountFrom. Is there a way how I can store two values when the user selects an option, like for instance the Iban and Currency into separate variables?

```
function getAccountFrom() {
    var username = $("#hiddenUsername").val();

    var url = "http://localhost:63723/api/BankAccountsApi/GetBankAccounts/?username=" + username + "&id=2";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var table = "<select id=\"ddlAccountFrom\">";

            table += "<option value=\"-1\">Select an Account</option>";
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                table += "<option value=\"" + val.Iban + "\">" + val.Iban + " | " + val.Currency + " | " + val.Balance + "</option>";

            });
            table += "</select>";
            $('#divAccountFrom').html(table);
    });
}
```

I am using the ddlAccountFrom in this function..

```
function Transfer() {
    var accountFrom = $("#ddlAccountFrom").val();
    var accountTo = $("#txtAccountTo").val();
    var amount = $("#txtAmount").val();


    var url = "http://localhost:63723/api/BankAccountsApi/TransferFunds/?  
    ibanFrom=" + accountFrom + "&ibanTo=" + accountTo + "&amount=" + amount;

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    })

    .error (function () {
        alert("Not enough balance! The amount entered exceed the balance found in this account. Please try again.");
    })

}
```

Comment: Well, you should probably show your code for when the user selects an option, but in general you can just concatenate the values using a separator and put it in the `value` of the option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data-custom attribute, like this:

```
table += "<option value=\"" + val.Iban + "\" data-currency=\"" + val.Currency + "\">" + val.Iban + " | " + val.Currency + " | " + val.Balance + "</option>";
```

To access variable see [jquery-cant-get-data-attribute-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351282/jquery-cant-get-data-attribute-value)
So you can read:

```
var selectedCurrency= $("#ddlAccountFrom :selected").data('currency');
```

Comment: Is data-currency a variable?

Comment: Yes you can read by jQuery(your selector).data('currency') or jQuery(your selector).attr('data-currency').

Comment: Like this --- var currency = $("#ddlAccountFrom").data('currency'); -- ??

Comment: I created an alert to output the currecy, and it is showing as undefined --> alert($('#ddlAccountFrom').data("currency"));

Comment: Sorry you're right you should use $("#ddlAccountFrom :selected").data('currency');

Answer (score 0):

You could :

1. Concatenate your 2 data in 1 string with a separator (for ex `myIban#myCurrency`) and then split your value to get back your 2 distinct data
2. Listen to your dropdown changes, for example adding a `onchange=updateData(val.Iban, val.Currency)` attribute to your option html, and in your js :

   ```
   var currentIban, currentCurrency;

   function updateData(iban, currency) {
       currentIban = iban;
       currentCurrency = currency;
   }
   ```
3. Add a data-custom attribute, like data-currency or data-iban