# Finding the data attribute value of a parent div several levels up with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to access the nearest div from the anchor tag that has a data-id attribute.

`.parent().parent().parent()` works but I am really trying to avoid doing that.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-id="@customer.Id">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            @customer.Name
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default js-deleteCustomer" href="#" title="Delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

**I tried the following:**

```
var customerId = $(this).closest("div:has(*[data-id])").attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want

```
var customerId = $(this).closest("div[data-id]").attr('data-id');
```

`:has(*[data-id])` doesn't match an element with that attribute. It matches an element that *contains another element* with that attribute. The element that's matched probably doesn't have this same attribute, which would explain why `:has(*[data-id])` doesn't work. For instance, it would match the outer div, not the inner div, in the following:

```
<div>
  <div data-id="@customer.Id"></div>
</div>
```

To match an element that has an attribute, simply attach the attribute selector directly without using `:has()`.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. As you said .data() and .attr() both work. The only difference is .data() returns the actual number and .attr returns it as a string.

Comment: @Blake Rivell: Ah, fair enough. I forgot that .data() performs type conversions.

Comment: I actually just realized my main problem was that in my actual code I was using the name data-customerId instead of data-id. It seems that capital letters dont work with data attribute. Were you aware of this?

Comment: @Blake Rivell: I wasn't. Searching turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351282/jquery-cant-get-data-attribute-value/17351380#17351380), which adds that this behavior is specific to .data().